# Call navigationController from AppDelegate

Tags: swift4, onesignal

Now I am implementing onesignal notification, when user click on notification I want to open specific Viewcontroller.

Here is my code at AppDelegate

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let detailBrand = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PagerOverviewControlerID") as! PagerOverviewControler
detailBrand.getValue = value
navigationController?.pushViewController(detailBrand, animated: true)
```

This code is working fine if I put it in any ViewController Class but inside AppDelegate it doesn't.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you have to understand that the `Appdelgate`  is not a `UIViewController`,

therefore you can't use `pushViewController(detailBrand, animated: true)` because you are not exactly in a `UIVewController`  to be able to do so, But Instead you can initiate a `UINavigatetionController` set it as your root then push from it.

and your code should be something like this

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let profileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PagerOverviewControlerID") as! PagerOverviewControler
rootViewController.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

Also keep in mind you should place it inside the `didFinishLaunchWithOption` method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
```